# Firebug - cant see console.log output when run from .js file

Tags: javascript, debugging

I am using mozilla developers edition with embed firebug. When i use console.log() function from inside source javascript file, i cant see its output in firebug console. 
When i type function directly into console prompt, everything is ok.

Why is that?

Comment: Does `alert` / `window.alert` work?

Comment: Yes, it does works ok.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You seem to have a very specific error, but you don't have any code that shows the problem itself. This makes this question impossible to answer, since the reasons are pure guesses. It could even be a bug in your RAM, a falty capacitator, a wrong bit in a file, a slight bug on Firebug, an error on your code that stops the execution of the entire Javascript..... As you can see, the possibilities are endless.

Answer (score 0):

Disable firebug and see if console prompt appear in build-in developer tool.
If yes, reinstall firebug.

Comment: Actually i dont have firebug installed as extension i cant disable it/reinstall. Its build in my firefox developers edition.

Comment: I also use Firefox Developer Edition and I don't have build-in firebug. Check that you have marked "JS" in console view.

Comment: The issue most likely is a SyntaxError that is being caught with a `try .. catch(e)` block. But, there's no way to know without having some code.

Comment: Okay, this is example: http://liveweave.com/0bazIp Alert works fine, console log does nothing, if i paste it into console direstly it returns just undefined.

Comment: @adam767667 It works fine for me... I have the non-developer version of Firefox. Try to update your Firefox.

Comment: Hard to say, it works for me fine, alert and console.log show as they should. Try `console.error("lorem");`